# Ignore certain file types when forcing lower case URL's with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using this code to force URL's to be lowercase only:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]

# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]

# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works, although isn't ideal. It's also rewriting the URL's for .js files (for example jqueryblockUI.js) which is causing the scripts to not be found.

How can I exclude certain file types like .js and .css from this?

Comment: Do you have access to apache config?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I exclude certain file types like .js and .css from this?

Preceede the whole process with a another rule, that checks if the requested path ends with one of the file extensions you want to exclude – some expression like `\.(js|css)$` – and then uses the skip flag to jump over the next X rules, same as you do with the check for whether there still are upper-case letters.

And if you have access to the central server configuration (since you tagged the question `.htaccess`, I presume you have not – but still, consider this a nice-to-know perhaps), you could use a [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) directive – that offers, among other things, some (very) basic string functions, one of them being `tolower`, that could do all that case conversion in one go.

For performance reasons I’d perhaps recommend, that in lack of that possibility, you perhaps use some server-side scripting language, if available, that you just direct *all* requests (apart from the JS/CSS files, as above) to, and that then calls it’s own version of a tolowercase function to get that job done in one go as well, and then issues the redirect header.